# performSegue after completion handler

Tags: swift, segue

**ANSWER BELOW**

Im facing a little issue that you may help me with.

the app Im working on allows you to request for content based on your location.

the first ViewController is somewhat a form that grab your location / a specified location + some other information to target specific answers.

I need to perform a segue to pass the "question" variables to my second ViewController where I load "answers" with a query based on the question details.

What is causing me trouble is that, whenever the question is geolocalized, I can't retrieve the information using prepareForSegue because it doesn't wait for the geoPoint to be made (completed).The second controller display my latitude and longitude as nil.

I see that I can call the "prepareForSegue" method using "perfomSegueWithIdentifier", and retrieve the information in my second view controller but it perform the segue twice... How can I trigger the segue only when Im ready but using the prepareForSegue data parameter I need to preserve?

Is there a way to pass variable from one controller to another using performSegue?
Any help would be awesome.

Also, while I don't think the code is relevant for my question, here is the code I use.

geoPointing method

```
@IBAction func doPostQuestion(sender: UIButton) {

        var thereQ:PFObject = PFObject(className: "tquestion")

        if(somewhereLabel.text == "my location"){
            println("Location is geolocalized")
            PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
                (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    self.geoLati = geoPoint.latitude as Double
                    self.geoLong = geoPoint.longitude as Double
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_results", sender:self)  // call prepareForSegue when ready but implies to have a segue done on click... (performed twiced)
                }
            }

        }
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

prepareForSegue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if(segue.identifier == "goto_results"){

                // Get Label
                let theDestination = (segue.destinationViewController as displayAnswersViewController)
                theDestination.lat = self.geoLati
                theDestination.lng = self.geoLong
        }
    }
```

**ANSWER SOLUTION:**

As suggested, to solve this problem you just need to create your segue from your viewController1 to your viewController2 and not from a button. This way you can trigger prepareForSegue programatically using the "performSegue" method that will call prepareForSegue anyway.

Comment: Did you connect the segue from the first view controller to the second view controller directly, and not from the button in the first view controller?

Comment: I did connect the segue from the button to the second controller yes. then I used prepareForSegue with my segue identifier. The segue is working, it's just I would need to wait for a localization call to be completed before segue is performed. If It doesn't wait the location variable is nil on the other side (second controller)

Comment: If you want to trigger a segue programmatically, you should connect the segue from the first view controller to the second view controller directly. Do not connect it from the button, or it will be called twice. Then you can trigger it when you background task is completed.

Comment: Ok, never thought about that. I'll give it a shot! thanks

Comment: ok it works. you should post this as an answer you I can validate it. I've edited my question to add the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you just need to create your segue from your viewController1 to your viewController2 and not from a button. This way you can trigger prepareForSegue programatically using the "performSegue" method that will call prepareForSegue anyway.